# PHP function returning thumbnail, not actual image

Tags: php

This is kind of a follow-up to my previous PHP question. After ALFEaton helped me with the code, I had some additional changes to make to add extra functionality. However, I am having one small problem, and I can't seen to figure it out. The code is fairly well commented, so it should be easy to read:

```
<?php
class Functions {
/** 
 * Allows you to save two copies of an image;
 * the resized copy, and the actual copy
 * 
 * @param $file - URL to get images from */
public function resize_image($file) {
    // Gets the file name
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $filename_thumb = 'thumbs/' . $path_parts['filename'] . '.png';
    $filename = 'gallery/' . $path_parts['filename'] . '.png';

    if (!file_exists($filename_thumb)) {
        //Creates an image from the URL
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);

        //Defining the desired thumbnail size, and the current one
        $thumb_size = 150;
        $width = imagesx($image);
        $height = imagesy($image);

        //Defining image aspect ratio
        $original_aspect = $width / $height;
        $thumb_aspect = $thumb_size / $thumb_size;

        if ($original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect) {
            // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
            $new_height = $thumb_size;
            $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_size);
        } else {
            // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
            $new_width = $thumb_size;
            $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_size);
        }

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);

        // Resize and crop
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0 - ($new_width - $thumb_size) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
        0 - ($new_height - $thumb_size) / 2, // Center the image vertically
        0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
        imagepng($thumb, $filename_thumb, 9);
    } else {
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $image_large = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            imagepng($image_large, $filename, 9);
        } else {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
}

/** 
 * Adds required HTML nodes to index.php
 * 
 * @author AlfEaton from Stack Overflow */
public function getImages() {
    //Returns the index page
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc -> loadHTMLFile('http://hathorarts.deviantart.com/gallery/');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    //Selects the linked thumbnail images
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $nodes = $xpath -> query('//a[@class="thumb"]');

    // Get the URL for each actual image, and build the links
    $output = new DOMDocument;
    foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
        $source_pre = $node -> getAttribute('data-super-img');
        $source = str_replace("/PRE", "", $source_pre);
        $this -> resize_image($source);

        $path_parts = pathinfo($source);
        $path_parts_filename = $path_parts['filename'];
        $filename = 'thumbs/' . $path_parts_filename . '.png';
        $filename_original = 'gallery/' . $path_parts_filename . '.png';

        $image_thumb = $output -> createElement('img');
        $image_thumb -> setAttribute('class', 'image_thumb');
        $image_thumb -> setAttribute('src', $filename);

        $link = $output -> createElement('a');
        $link -> setAttribute('href', $filename_original);
        $link -> setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox-gallery');
        $link -> appendChild($image_thumb);

        $output -> appendChild($link);
    }
    print $output -> saveHTML();
}
}
?>
```

The thumbnail part works fine. But the $link href attribute returns the thumbnail. This is my file set-up for this project -

[image]

With my PHP functions in the functions.php file.
The code outputs the actual images and thumbnails, but it doesn't display the actual image, just the thumbnail.

Comment: so... figure out where/what the 'full size' url is, and use that for your $link instead of the thumbnail link...

Comment: @MarcB Did you read the code? If you look at it, you can see from my set-up that it's the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this may sound like a silly question, but are you certain you are creating the full size images with these functions? Your resize_image function only creates the full size image if the thumbnail file exists - it doesn't create it in your thumbnail routine:

Your code:

```
if (!file_exists($filename_thumb)) {
    //Creates an image from the URL
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);

    //Defining the desired thumbnail size, and the current one
    //*and carry on with your thumbnail creation*
} else {
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        $image_large = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        imagepng($image_large, $filename, 9);
}
```

Should you be putting the last line - imagepng($image_large, $filename, 9); in the thumbnail routine also?

Suggested:

```
if (!file_exists($filename_thumb)) {
    //Creates an image from the URL
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagepng($image, $filename, 9);

    //Defining the desired thumbnail size, and the current one
    //*and carry on with your thumbnail creation*
} else {
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        $image_large = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        imagepng($image_large, $filename, 9);
}
```

Comment: I am certain that it creates the full size images, because it outputs to a local folder. I will make that change however, that's a good idea.